# Determine whether any value from vector in R is found in another vector

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame that has two columns, `a` and `b`. Both `a` and `b` have vectors of different lengths, and I want to create another column, called `boolean`, which should be true when at least one value from the vector in `b` is present in the vector in column `a`. However, I used the following logic and I'm getting a `false` for all rows, even though I should be getting `true` for rows 1, 3 and 4. A reproducible example of my attempt is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
data_frame <-
  tribble(
    ~a,                                    ~b,
    c("50", "50", "50", "3"),              c("1", "2", "3"),
    c("17", "50", "50", "50"),             "19",
    c("50", "28", "50", "3"),              c("30", "28", "29"),
    c("21", "19", "50", "50", "50"),       c("19", "20", "18")
  )

data_frame %>% 
  mutate(
    boolean = if_else(
      any(b %in% a),
      "yes",
      "no"
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   a         b         boolean
#>   <list>    <list>    <chr>  
#> 1 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> no     
#> 2 <chr [4]> <chr [1]> no     
#> 3 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> no     
#> 4 <chr [5]> <chr [3]> no
```

Is there something wrong with how I am using the `any` command? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `purrr` solution with `map2()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data_frame %>%
  mutate(boolean = map2_chr(a, b, ~ if_else(any(.y %in% .x), "yes", "no")))

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   a         b         boolean
#   <list>    <list>    <chr>  
# 1 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> yes    
# 2 <chr [4]> <chr [1]> no     
# 3 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> yes    
# 4 <chr [5]> <chr [3]> yes
```

or with `pmap()`:

```
data_frame %>%
  mutate(boolean = pmap_chr(select(., a, b),
                            ~ if_else(any(.y %in% .x), "yes", "no")))
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R option using `Vectorize` + `intersect`

```
within(data_frame,  boolean <- ifelse(lengths(Vectorize(intersect)(a,b)),"yes","no"))
```

or `Map` + `intersect`

```
within(data_frame,  boolean <- ifelse(lengths(Map(intersect,a,b)),"yes","no"))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  a         b         boolean
  <list>    <list>    <chr>
1 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> yes
2 <chr [4]> <chr [1]> no
3 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> yes
4 <chr [5]> <chr [3]> yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `rowwise` to perform this operation on each row :

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame %>% 
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(boolean = if_else(any(b %in% a),"yes","no"))

#   a         b       boolean
#  <list>    <list>    <chr>  
#1 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> yes    
#2 <chr [4]> <chr [1]> no     
#3 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> yes    
#4 <chr [5]> <chr [3]> yes
```

---

Similar variations :

Without `ifelse` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data_frame %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(boolean = c('no', 'yes')[any(b %in% a) + 1])
```

Or with `map2_lgl` :

```
data_frame %>% 
     mutate(boolean = c('no', 'yes')[map2_lgl(b, a, ~any(.x %in% .y)) + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you after this?

```
data_frame %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(boolean = if_else(any(b %in% a), "yes", "no"))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  a         b         boolean
  <list>    <list>    <chr>  
1 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> yes    
2 <chr [4]> <chr [1]> no     
3 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> yes    
4 <chr [5]> <chr [3]> yes
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmap`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data_frame %>% 
   mutate(boolean = pmap_chr(., ~  c("no", "yes")[1+any(..2 %in% ..1)]))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  a         b         boolean
#  <list>    <list>    <chr>  
#1 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> yes    
#2 <chr [4]> <chr [1]> no     
#3 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> yes    
#4 <chr [5]> <chr [3]> yes
```